# Eclipse's error on startup in windows 7

Tags: eclipse, jvm

Good day.

I decided to learn Java. I installed JDK and downloaded `eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32` for windows 7.

But i can't launch eclipse because i always receive the message:

```
Error: couldn't find Java SE Runtime Environment
```

I tried to reinstall the JDK but installer gave me such message:

```
Error 1723, There is a problem with this Windows Installer package.
A DLL required for this install to complete couldn't be run."
```

At least here is information that eclipse gave to me:

```
Java was started but returned exit code=2 

C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion =1.5 -Xms40m
-Xmx334m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-os Win32
-ws Win32
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library
C:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.Iauncher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v2010
0810\eclipse_1309.dll
-startup C:\eclipse\pIugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar -exitdata 1760_50
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -vm C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe -vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507jar
```

---

Here is a picture of the error. I suppose that i could make few mistakes in the log.

[image]

Comment: I had this problem after I installed a bunch of updates to 4.23.0. Installing the latest release of Eclipse did not solve the problem. I installed 4.24.0 and the problem went away. I have no idea why. Note that I am running Windows 10. I am not sure if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your `eclipse.ini` (right beside the `eclipse.exe`) in order to:

- specify a full JVM path (`-vm` argument: `-vm C:/Prog/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll` for instance). Don't use the one in `C:\Windows\System32`.
- not specify the jar used for the launcher.library

See [this **`eclipse.ini`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) as an example.

Answer (score 3):

My employer also pushed out a Java 7 update to my machine after which I started getting the same Eclipse error on startup.  I fixed it by removing the following files:

- C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
- C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe
- C:\Windows\System32\javaws.exe

Eclipse starts up successfully now.

Comment: Deleting the files in System32 directory is asking for unnecessary trouble. You have to do it if you are absolutely sure of what you are doing.

Comment: Java is not a Windows system file. Adding java.exe or any other Java runtime executable to the System32 directory is asking for unnecessary trouble.

Answer (score 2):

```
-vm
C:/Java/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

you should specify jvm.dll file path to any bundle of the eclipse .ini file (eclipse.ini,sts.ini)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all of the tricks stated above and nothing was able to resolve my problem. Changing the path way, registry being corrupted, few dlls weren't able to be deleted and so on and on... I used Fixit it delete whatever I saw with the name JAVA. I tried installing GRE/JVM separately, nothing worked what so ever.

Solution..

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_offline_download.xml

Use offline install of JAVA or some people call it silently install JAVA. This fixed my problem that I couldn't fix in two days. After this I was able to install eclipse without getting any pathway error message, or dll related messages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after a Java update provided by my employer. Everything was working just fine and then the update arrived. Suddenly Eclipse Helios Service Release 2 did not launch giving me the same error msg that you got.

The solution was to download the latest JRE from www.java.com, JRE 1.6 update 30. I did not have to do any changes to eclipse.ini at all.

Hope this will help someone who is experiencing the same issue. :-)

Comment: After installing [Java SE Runtime Environment 7u4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre-7u4-download-1591157.html) I could start Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as of "ExiRe" and tried modifying the eclipse.ini, but to no avail. Then by following the eclipse logs I found it's trying to use the default java exes in System32. I deleted the three Java files from System32 folder, specified the -vm args in eclipse.ini and started Eclipse again.

eclipse started fine on the 32 bit combi(both java and eclipse 32 bit versions) but not on the 64 bit combi.

So far I'm using 32 bit combi. If anyone could figure out how to get it work on 64 bit combi please respond.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after installing jdk 7 update 9. Something must be wrong with this installation. I removed java/javaw/javaws exe files (as suggested in the above comment) from windows\system32 and eclipse started fine. Reinstalling JRE did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the system32 java files and then copied the new jre folder from the new java jdk 7 to the folder for eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and it took me 2 days to fix it. I removed `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` from Windows/System32 folder.
Eclipse has just opened, I'm happy to see my favorite IDE again.