# Eclipse crashes when coding in java. Exit code=-1073740771

Tags: eclipse, crash, java

I've downloaded the Android ADT bundle so that I can learn to code Android applications. I also downloaded every package on the SDK manager.

Unfortunately, when I try to code anything in Java Eclipse crashes upon opening content assist.

Basically, when I type the dot operator the content assist box opens and suggests methods as per the norm. However, when I type anything after this point the content assist box tries to open the accompanying window with API information about the method I'm trying to invoke. At this point Eclipse crashes, without fully loading the API window.

If I don't specify the -vm argument in the eclipse.ini file the windows error window says that 'Java(TM) platform SE binary has stopped working' and gives me an error window afterwards as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfdOc.png

If I do specify the -vm argument(and I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly) the windows error window say that 'eclipse.exe has stopped working' and does not give any more information.

Having tried several things and having looked everywhere I'm stumped.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587518/eclipses-error-on-startup-in-windows-7) answer.

Comment: I specified the jvm.dll in my jdk root folder as the vm path and now it's eclipse.exe that stops working. On a brighter note, the whited-out box now loads and appears to be API information about the selected method.

Comment: I also tracked down the current error in the Event Viewer: Faulting application name: eclipse.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4fad6d5e
Faulting module name: mshtml.dll, version: 10.0.9200.16635, time stamp: 0x51b7ad9b
Exception code: 0xc0000005

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: I had this problem after I installed a bunch of updates to 4.23.0. Installing the latest release of Eclipse did not solve the problem. I installed 4.24.0 and the problem went away. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Update KB4463318 has solved this issue.

Comment: please ellaborate as to what in the KB actually fixes as there are a number of patches in that windows update.