# Eclipse not start during run from elclipse.exe

Tags: jsp

MY eclipse not working ... when i run it it give the error  : JAVA WAS STARTED BUT RETURN THE CODE :13 c:\POGRAM\ORACLE\JAVA\JAVAPATH\JAVAW.EXE DOSGI.REQUIREDJAVAVERSION=1.5

THE POPUP msg come like that[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKauc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly says that this eclipse version needs java 1.5 or onwards.
So install jdk1.5 or onwards to resolve it.

### See Also

- [Eclipse's error on startup in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587518/eclipses-error-on-startup-in-windows-7)
- [Eclipse JVM configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410511/eclipse-jvm-configuration)